# Purpose of digital circuit

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

I have the following transmission gates circuit.
[image]

I have some difficulties understanding the purpose of this circuit. It has the same structure like a flip flop but works differently.
This is the equivalent circuit when CLK is 1 or 0:
[image]

I would be grateful if someone could clarify me.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. You're asking for a purpose of this circuit? Perhaps it is to create an exercise and educate you about the subject.

Comment: The functionality I mean...

Comment: Do you understand how transmission gates and tristate devices work? (Again, I'm not understanding what you're not understanding.)

Comment: Yes, I undersant how they work. It's so hard to understand that I want to know the functionality. Stop acting so damn smart.

Comment: @Baciu: I think there is a language problem here on your part. KingDuken is a helpful member of the site. Please try to see what might be missing in your question.

Comment: I apologize if my behavior is seen as rude. I'm genuinely curious as to what you're not understanding. Is there something specific you're not understanding? i.e. Are you curious what the feedback networks in your circuit? Are you curious why there's open circuits when CLK goes high and low?

Comment: For instance: what is the output value when the clock is high (for a given D - 0 or 1) ?  But when the clock is low ?

Comment: I believe there is a typo in the diagram. The second TG is flipped vertically; the inversion bubble should be on top instead of bottom.

Comment: @Greg Yes, makes sense. If so, the circuit works as an flip flop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there is a typo in the diagram. If the second TG would be flipped vertically, the circuit would behave like a flip flop. 
[image]